# Making a model available to the layout globally in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am just starting out with Laravel and I'm putting together a quick blog site as an exercise.

I have a posts model that has posts, with content. I can list the posts, display a single post, and create a post.

I have created a categories table and model that will be related to posts (posts belong to categories). I would like to have a dropdown menu listing all the categories in my navigation layout that spans the entire app.

What's the best practice to allow the view to access that data across the entire app? It seems wrong to need to add the following to each controller method just so I can pass that data along.

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses) are made for.

You can register a callback function that is called everytime a certain view is rendered:

```
View::composer('layout', function($view){
   $view->with('categories', Category::all());
});
```

You can put this code in `app/filters.php` or create a new `app/composers.php` and include it at the end of `app/start/global.php` with:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Comment: Very helpful. I added it in app/filters.php. Would a composer be a best practice? I think I'll need to learn more about caching so I'm not making the same query each time my page gets hit! Thank you.

Comment: Yes I would consider that best practice. Also Laravel has some very simple [caching capabilities for queries](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#caching-queries). You can just do `Category::remember(10)->get()` and the query will be cached for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 5 was released today.  So this is how you would do it in the new Laravel.  To do this, you want to use a View Composer [[docs]](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers).

```
// App/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer('posts.*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\PostComposer');
    }

}

// App/Http/Composers/PostComposer.php
<?php namespace App\Http\Composers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class PostComposer {

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('categories', Categories::all());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am very excited about Laravel 5.  It seems to have followed some traits from Express.js and Node.

Comment: View composers still work the same way in Laravel 5 as they did in Laravel 4. The only difference is that now it's best practice to register them in the boot method of a Service Provider.